# Listar vários registros do MYSQL no email PHP para enviar tudo de uma vez

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema imobiliário que lista vários registros do MYSQL. Estou com este código abaixo para que estes vários registros sejam enviados em um único email, porém ele só envia um registro.

Vejam o código:

```
<?php require_once('conexao.php'); ?>
<?php
$sqlxml = "select conta.dominio,conta.id,conta.modelo,imoveis.id,imoveis.cod,imoveis.titulo,imoveis.vvenda,imoveis.vtemporada,imoveis.vanual,imoveis.tipo,fotos.cod,fotos.foto,imoveis.descricao,imoveis.cidade, imoveis.data, imoveis.endereco, conta.nome, imoveis.dormitorio, imoveis.banheiro, imoveis.atotal, imoveis.areatotalmedida, imoveis.bairro from conta inner join imoveis on conta.id = imoveis.cod inner join fotos on fotos.cod=imoveis.id where imoveis.status='2' AND imoveis.vvenda < '500000' GROUP BY imoveis.id";
$rsqlxml = mysql_query($sqlxml)
or die ("Banco XML não abre!");

$quebra_linha = "\n";
$emailsender = "guaraparivirtual@gmail.com";
$emailorigem = "contato@roteirodoimovel.com.br";
$assunto = "Roteiro do Imóvel - Sugestão de imóveis";

while($rowxml = mysql_fetch_array($rsqlxml))
{
    $mensagemHTML = "
    <strong>Id:</strong> ".$rowxml[3]. "<br>
    <strong>Título:</strong> ".$rowxml[5]. "<br>
    <strong>Categoria:</strong> ".$imvtipo. "<br>
    <strong>Imóvel para:</strong> ".$tipodoimovel. "<br>
    <strong>Valor:</strong> ".number_format($rowxml[6], 2, ',', ' '). "<br>
    <strong>Cidade:</strong> ".$imvcidade. "<br>
    <strong>Bairro:</strong> ".$mostrarbairroemail. "<br>
    <img src='http://www.roteirodoimovel.com.br/cp/clientes/".$rowxml[4]."/".$rowxml[3]."/".$rowxml[11]."' width='170' height='127'><br>
    <strong>Descrição:</strong> ".$rowxml[12]. "<br>
    <strong>Visualizar:</strong> ".$rowxml['0']."/".$rowxml['2']."/detalhes.php?idimovel=".$rowxml['3']."<br>
    "; 
 }

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1".$quebra_linha;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8".$quebra_linha;
$headers .= "From: ".$emailorigem.$quebra_linha;
$headers .= "Return-Path: " . $emailorigem . $quebra_linha;
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$emailsender.$quebra_linha;
$mailsend=mail($emailsender, $assunto, $mensagemHTML, $headers, "-r". $emailsender); 
?>
```

O que foi feito de errado?

Answer (score 0):

Só é enviado o último registro porque a cada volta no while `$mensagemHTML` tem seu valor rescrito.

Para resolver isso define a variável antes do while e faça a concatenação da string com `.=`

mude:

```
$mensagemHTML = "longo html";
```

Para:

```
$mensagemHTML = "";
while(...){
    $mensagemHTML .= "longo html";
```